# Calling click event of a button serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I click or load the `click()` event of a button in codebehind?
I already tried

```
      btn.Click();
```

but this gives an error. I am using ASP.NET

Comment: Which technology are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error?

Answer (score 27):

I will assume that you have a button called Button1
and that you have double clicked it to create an event handler.

To simulate the button click in code, you simply 
call the event handler:

Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e).

e.g. in your Page Load Event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This simulates the button click from within your code.
    Button1_Click(Button1, EventArgs.Empty);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do some stuff in the button click event handler.
}
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out in this answer that the event args are using the EventArgs.Empty opposed to 'newing them up'. This will save you some resources but is also a subtle reason why this answer is better :)

Comment: Whatever code is running inside `Button1_Click(..)` should be in its own method, `Foo()`.  And then both `Page_Load(..)` and `Button1_Click(..)` should call `Foo();`.  When you are tempted to invoke event handlers directly think about whether that is actually what you intended, or if you want to just perform the same ultimate action.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the context provided by the sender and eventargs then you can just refactor to create a method (eg DoStuff()) and make your event handler just call that. Then when you want to call the same functionality from elsewhere you can just call DoStuff(). It really depends on whether you want to actually simulate a click or not. If you want to simulate a click then other methods are better.

Answer (score 4):

Do you wish to call all the event handlers attached to the button, or just one?

If just one, call the handler:

```
 btn.btn_Click(btn, new EventArgs());
```

If all of them, trigger the event:

```
 var tmpEvent = btn.Click;
 if (tmpEvent != null)
      tmpEvent(btn, new EventArgs());
```

Comment: Button1.Button1_Click(Button1, new EventArgs());  dose not works can you expain your code ??

Comment: This results in Error CS0079: The event 'LinkButton.Click' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
YourButton_Click(sender, e);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit try this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
}

 void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

in the .cs page

Comment: yeah i already did this... but i need to call button1_Click in code behind... without clicking on the button!

Answer (score 1):

Just call the buttons click function.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1178012.aspx

Instead of trying to call the event just call the function that event uses.

> Example: btn.Click() calls
>   btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> so you should call the function btn_Click(btn,new
>   EventArgs());

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time ago, but here is my solution

You can use:

```
btn.PerformClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   functionName();
}
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   functionName();
}

public void functionName()
{

//function code goes here, and call this function where ever you want

}
```

try this one.......

Answer (score 0):

```
 YourButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

This works for me.

Comment: i think it is for WPF