# How to call load event in button click event

Tags: c#, winforms

How to call load event in button click event
I tried by calling `Event Handler`

```
this.load += EventHandler(this.Form_Load)//This event called from button click event
```

But it does not calls the `Form_Load` Event.
Could anyone help on this?

Comment: Why do you try to call the Load event over a Button? this does not makes any sense because the Load event and the Button click event are made for absolutely different behaviors

Comment: Hi check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203041/calling-click-event-of-a-button-serverside possible duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Venson.My requirment is loading the child form with the static values of parent form Load Event.if I did update in child form that does not gets reflected in child form because the static values are in parent form load event.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to call Form_load.

```
Form_Load(this, null);
```

But what you try todo makes no sense for me.

Answer (score 3):

Your best route to resolve this is to place the particular portions of your Form_Load event into a separate sub/function and then to call that function instead.

```
Sub Form_Load(sender, e)
  '
  'call to routine
  ProcessFormLoadStuff
  '
End Sub

Sub ProcessFormLoadStuff()
  '
  ' Your code here
  '
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click(sender, e)
  'call to routine
  ProcessFormLoadStuff
End Sub
```

Finally the way in which you RAISE an event is explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h7a2kh64(v=VS.80).aspx

Whether it is logically acceptable to raise a Form_Load event AFTER the Form has loaded raises some hypothetical issues in correctness. and like many of the other members have stated, its not a usually done thing - meaning its not a text-book method!