# Calling click event (CommandEventArgs) of a button serverside

Tags: asp.net, buttonclick

I refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203493/5529860).
I also use ASP.NET and I got the following button click event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

When I try to call the click event serverside I get an error. It says that it can't convert `System.EventArgs` to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs`.

Is it possible to call the event the same way as in the article I did refer to?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have it declared with CommandEventArgs? It is ok to have it so, but you need to make sure to provide correct arguments then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely call it still, it is just a normal C# method. But the caveat is that you need to provide correct values as command name and command argument, as this handler most likely uses one or both of these.

```
string commandName = "command name here";
object commandArgument = <argument here>;
Button1_Click(sender, new CommandEventArgs(commandName, commandArgument));
```

That is assuming you call it inside Page_Load, as the post you refer to. If not, make sure to provide reference to correct control as `sender`.