# button press on webbrowser

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div class="step__footer">
    <input type="hidden" name="complete" value="1" />

    <button type="submit" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn">
        <span class="btn__content">Complete order</span>
    </button>
    <a class="step__footer__previous-link" href="">
        <svg class="previous-link__icon icon--chevron icon" xmlns="">
        </svg>
        Return to payment method
    </a>
</div>
```

And problem is I don't know how to do a click on that button in background process on webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an [ASP button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can [call the click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203041/calling-click-event-of-a-button-serverside).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define a class in C# for the object scripting helper to handle any methods called between web browser document and C#:
check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx